# Create utility endpoint to be implemented by different microservices

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, microservices

I want to to create one custom end point having utility methods to be used by different microservices by passing there specification. Example

Localhost:8080/context-path/readFile/{fileType}
Which will be having kind of utility methods used by multiple Ms based upon different fileType and I will put all this within a utility Jar

So system1 can implement this end point and pass their file type and used this sepcification and same fot system2 ..can someone guide me ?

I know @endpoint ,@controllerendpoint works in similar way but i dont want this to be part of actuator end point and my utility end point will be part of a utility jar.